# Visual Studio Code disable sidebar code slider thing

Tags: sidebar, visual-studio-code

How do I get rid of the sidebar thing below?:

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### The thing is called [Minimap](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-minimap).

---

#### Recommended: To change it from within VS Code...

- on **all systems**, the easiest way is to use the menu: `View` -> `Toggle Minimap` (as shown on the screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of VSCode menu]

- on **all systems**, you can also press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> <sub>(on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is replaced by <kbd>⌘</kbd>) and search for `Toggle Minimap` within the Command Palette.</sub>

---

#### [As with all settings in VS Code, you can also change it via `settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

- on **Windows**  / **Linux**, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> <sub>(it's a comma)</sub>. (This could also work on **OSX**, but I have not found a reference and I cannot test it myself).
- on **all systems**, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is replaced by <kbd>⌘</kbd>)  and then search for `Preferences: Open user settings`.

Now, you should see a new file-tab called `User settings` and in it a two-pane viewer with its own search bar.

There, you look for **`editor.minimap.enabled`** and change its value to **`false`**.  (You can also just add `"editor.minimap.enabled": false` to your `settings.json` and save it.)

*If you want to change it for your current project only, you can select `Workspace Settings` to the right of the setting window's search bar.*

**That's it!**

---

#### If you want to edit it from outside VS Code for some reason, open in...

- **Windows**: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`.
- **OSX**: `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`.
- **Linux**: `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`.

Then, just add **`"editor.minimap.enabled": false`** to your `settings.json` and save it.

*If you want to change it for your current project only, you can also look in your project's `.vscode`-folder - there, another `settings.json` can be found.*